# ORA-00942: Can select from "schema.table" but not "table"?

Tags: oracle, ora-00942

I experienced an ORA-00942 ("table or view does not exist") when executing

```
select * from brunch
```

However, no such problem when executing

```
select * from joe.brunch
```

May i know what is the issue here?

Comment: I am not too sure, how may i find out zerkms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unqualified, `BRUNCH` refers to a different object than `JOE.BRUNCH` in your current session.  You've got a couple of options to fix that.

1. Create a public synonym.  This will allow any user that has privileges on the `JOE.BRUNCH` table to access it by querying `BRUNCH`

   CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM brunch
      FOR joe.brunch
2. Create a private synonym.  This will allow just the current user to access the `JOE.BRUNCH` table by querying `BRUNCH`

   CREATE SYNONYM brunch
      FOR joe.brunch
3. Change the current schema for the current session to `JOE`.  This will cause all unqualified references in the current session to resolve to the `JOE` schema rather than to the current user's schema

   ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = JOE

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible causes

1) there is more than one object  (table,view, procedure, etc) called brunch.  Oracle does not know which one you are referring to.

2) most likely cause: the table exists in the joe schema but you are connecting as another user who has not been granted select on the joe.brunch object

Try

Grant select on joe.brunch to your_user

and try this and see how many objects match the name brunch

select *
from all_objects
where object_type in (‘TABLE’,'VIEW’)
and object_name = ‘brunch‘;

Comment: He **has** grants, otherwise he couldn't select from fully qualified table name

Comment: He connected to as user, but doesn't have a synonym created to the joe schema.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the table I was referencing (Flyway's [schema_version](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/how) table), was created with double quotes... and thus needed double quotes wherever it was referenced.

#### [Here's what Oracle says](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm#i27570):

> A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks (").
> If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must
> use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.

In practice, these worked:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA."schema_version";
SELECT * FROM "MYSCHEMA"."schema_version";
```

When this didn't (-> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist):

```sql
SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA.schema_version;
```