# the table/view doesn't exist by using different schema

Tags: sql, database-schema

1) To create a table under schema A.

```
create table test_PK (
     stdid INT NOT NULL,
     stdname VARCHAR(10),
     PRIMARY KEY(stdid)
     );

insert into test_pk values (10,'Bob');  //Here works fine
```

2) To execute:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,DELETE ON TEST_PK TO B;  //works fine
```

3) To use schema B to login the DB, while executing `select * from test_pk;`  it complains:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 12 Column: 14

Did I miss something?

Comment: I think you are confusing schema and user. When you granting access to table you are granting it to the user. The user B still needs to be able to login to the A's schema

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you need to specify the schema when logged in with a different user:

```
select * from A.test_pk
```

This post might also help: [ORA-00942: Can select from "schema.table" but not "table"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591569/ora-00942-can-select-from-schema-table-but-not-table) -- you can create a synonym to bypass having to specify the schema in your SELECT.

Comment: After executing,CREATE SYNONYM TEST_PK FOR A.TEST_PK; It can works now.